# HTML code button missing from Rich Text "standard" view after 2.5 upgrade

Tags: redactor, richtext, upgrades

After recently upgrading to Craft 2.5.x the HTML code view button is now missing from the "standard" Rich Text view, which means I can no longer edit all the custom HTML code I've added to those fields.

Do I have to create a custom Redactor config file to get HTML code view back, or should it still be included in the Standard config?

Comment: I don't have a custom redactor config file. I'm using the Craft standard view. Is the Craft standard view going to be updated with the change or is it now required that we create custom redactor configs to get source view back?

Comment: There's two config files in craft/config/redactor/ that are meant to be edited, Standard.js and Simple.js. Edit them to your needs and select a config from the Rich Text field settings.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to carlcs for pointing this out. If I edit the Standard.json file in craft/config/redactor/ as per these instructions (https://craftcms.com/help/redactor-ii-configs) it's fixed.

I find it odd that Craft 2.5 didn't come with this Redactor config fix included, rather than letting it break and leaving it up to developers to fix it. I can understand if you had custom configs, but the default Simple and Standard configs should come fixed with the install or upgrade, no?

Comment: Craft updates won't ever touch any file outside the craft/app/ folder. Download the manual update package from craftcms.com to get the updated config files.

Comment: Anyway to update the Default config? I only have two configs simple and standard, all of my fields have always used Default. So now I need to edit standard.json, then go change all my rich text fields to standard instead of default... or is there a way to update the default config?