# After updating to Craft 2.5, standard and custom rich text (Redactor) fields disappear

Tags: redactor

After updating to Craft 2.5, some rich text fields have disappeared from the CMS.[image: Field Missing]

While this similar to the [issue described here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/html-code-button-missing-from-rich-text-standard-view-after-2-5-upgrade), the answer did not fully resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looked like my custom Redactor configuration files needed to be updated to be compatible with the latest version of Redactor that was included with Craft 2.5.  The [This Craft support page](https://craftcms.com/support/redactor-ii-configs) described some of the changes, but these did not fully fix my issue.

I figured out that the structure of "formattingAdd" configuration had been updated. Once I followed the format [described on the Imperavi site](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#setting-formattingAdd), the fields started displaying again.

**Version 1 formattingAdd syntax:**

```
formattingAdd: [
    {
        tag: 'p',
        title: 'Disclaimer',
        class: 'disclaimer'
    },
    {
        tag: 'a',
        title: 'Secondary CTA',
        class: 'btn btn-default'
    }
]
```

**Version II formattingAdd syntax:**

```
formattingAdd: {
    'disclaimer-add': {
        title: 'Disclaimer',
        args: ['p', 'class', 'disclaimer', 'add']
    },
    'secondary-add': {
        title: 'Secondary CTA',
        args: ['a', 'class', 'btn btn-default', 'add']
    }
}
```